# Piece-wise density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that when your are given a piece-wise density function such as:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
4x, & 0< x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
4-4x, & \frac{1}{2}< x\leq1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The distribution function would be:
$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\int\limits_{0}^{x}4x\, dx, & 0< x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}4x\, dx + \int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}4-4x\, dx, & \frac{1}{2}< x\leq1 
\end{cases}$$

However, I do not quite understand why for $$\frac{1}{2}< x\leq1$$ the distribution function is:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}4x\, dx + \int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}4-4x\, dx$$

I would appreciate if someone could explain the logic behind this.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of a density $f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R^+}$ is given by 
\begin{align}
F(x)=\int_{0}^x f(s) ds
\end{align}
using your definition of $f$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
4x, & 0< x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
4-4x, & \frac{1}{2}< x\leq1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
we get for $x \in [0.5,1]$ due to the additivity of the integral
\begin{align}
F(x)=\int_{0}^x f(s) ds &= \int_0^{0.5}f(s)ds + \int_{0.5}^x f(s) ds \\
&=\int_0^{0.5}4s\,ds + \int_{0.5}^x 4-4s\, ds
\end{align}
which one could of course simplify even further.

Note, that in your definition for $F(x)$ you are using $x$ in the second integral as upper bound and argument There you might use $s$ for the argument as I did to avoid confusion.